# How to use coalesce to take sum

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3

Can I use `sum()` in `coalesce()`?

I want to use it in a stored function in Postgres.

For example

```
case (COALESCE(t3.Count3,0)+ COALESCE(t2.Count2,0) >= t4.Count4::float) 
then ( select (t4.Count4::float/((t3.Count3::float)+(t2.Count2::float))) * 100 as Count5 ) 
else ''0'' 
end as Count5
```

Comment: seems like you mix data types?..

Comment: siri want to add two values if it is null then given as zero. So i use coalesce function. Can you help me

Comment: please provide the whole query, data sample and structure

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: `else ''0'' ` should be `else 0`. You can't return a number in one `case` part and a string in another.

Comment: You are also missing a `when` for your `case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here because there are multiple issues in the code. Also though your title mentions `SUM` your code doesn't include it (though you do have `+` but that's not the same).

If this is part of a `SELECT` statement, then I'm guessing what you want is:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(t3.Count3,0)+ COALESCE(t2.Count2,0) >= t4.Count4::float
    THEN 100 * t4.Count4::float/(COALESCE(t3.Count3::float,0)+COALESCE(t2.Count2::float,0))
    ELSE 0
END as Count5
FROM MyTable
```